# Is there a fast way to assign mysql object result to selfdefined class?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm creating a lot of objects and I come across that I often assign each object column to each internal object variable one by one.

What I wounder is if there is a faster way to do the following?

```
public function load(){
    $result = $this->coredb->query("SELECT * FROM " . CORE_TBL_ORDER_LINE . " WHERE id=" . $this->id . " LIMIT 1");
    if($result !== false && $result->num_rows == 1){
        $obj = $result->fetch_object();

        // Can the following be done in a faster way? (Names do always match)
        $this->ISBN = $obj->ISBN;
        $this->type = $obj->type;
        $this->status = $obj->status;
        $this->updated = $obj->updated;
        $this->blocked = $obj->blocked;
        $this->created = $obj->created;
    }
    else
        $this->id = 0;
}
```

Comment: [PDOStatement::fetchObject](http://www.php.net/manual/pdostatement.fetchobject.php) with `$class_name` set?

Comment: http://us2.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-object.php. this allows setting the class name of the object to create

Comment: @Anthony Thanks! I think this is a good tip, I guess I have to add some extra functionality to make this work if I'm already inside the object that I want to assign the values to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PDO allows you to do it much better than MySQLi and makes your code portable. You could use the `fetch` method with `PDO::FETCH_INTO` flag set, as stated in PHP documentation:

```
/* or create an instance yourself and use it */
$user= new user();
$sth->setFetchMode( PDO::FETCH_INTO, $user);
$sth->execute();
$user= $sth->fetch( PDO::FETCH_INTO );
$sth->closeCursor();
print ($user->id);
```

PHP Documentation link: https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php

Comment: This is a nice way I must say, I'll give it a go even thought we use MySQLi for all our applications. This due to a former known utf-8 bug with older versions of PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do something like this:

```
public $row;

public function load(){
    $result = $this->coredb->query("SELECT * FROM " . CORE_TBL_ORDER_LINE . " WHERE id=" . $this->id . " LIMIT 1");
    if($result !== false && $result->num_rows == 1){

        $this->row = $result->fetch_object();

    }
    else
        $this->id = 0;
    }
```